# Change a css value (left:x) if a browser viewport is <1200px

Tags: jquery, css, browser, viewport

I have a wrap around my content on a webpage that has a width of 1200px. The wrap div is centered in the middle of my page with this css, `position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-600px;
    width:1200px;
    height:auto;`
 I need to use jQuery to change the left value from 50% to 0px if the browser viewport width is less then 1200px. Right now on an ipod for example, because the wrap is centered, my content on the left is cut off with no way to scroll to the side. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Even if you change the left value to 0px, the content will flow out of the right side of the page and you won't have a way to scroll over to see the content. You're going to need to remove absolute positioning to get your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you're using this technique to center the element? A much simpler way to do it, which would work just fine at smaller widths would be without absolute positioning and negative margins!

```
div#container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Here is a fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mDLZZ/). Drag the resizable pane to resize the window.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){
    if($(this).width() < 1200)
        $('div.wrap').css('left', 0);
    else 
       $('div.wrap').css('left', '50%');
}).resize();
```

Comment: Thanks! worked perfectly!, just had to add a css function to set the margin-left value to zero. <script>
$(function(){
 $(window).bind('resize', function(){
  if($(this).width() < 1200)
   $('#wrap').css({'left' : '0px', 'margin-left' : '0px'})
  else 
     $('#wrap').css('left', '50%');
 }).resize();
});
</script>